# Rosbag for sensor_msg/Imu

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd really appreciate it if someone could give me a bagfile containing data published to the topic [sensor_msgs/Imu](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Imu.html).

I have a [Sparkfun Razor IMU 14001](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14001) that I'm trying to use for odometry, but the [razor_imu_9dof](http://wiki.ros.org/razor_imu_9dof) package doesn't support my version of the Razor IMU. So, I can't get real data being published on this topic to test my odometry code, which is why I'd really like to have a rosbag that I could use instead to test. Any IMU that publishes on this topic should work. Two examples are Razor IMU 10125 and Razor IMU 10736 (both have been retired by SparkFun).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263596/rosbag-for-sensor_msg/imu/) by [atmosphericvibes](https://answers.ros.org/users/30709/atmosphericvibes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2017-06-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found one, thanks to a reddit user - http://www.kostasalexis.com/uploads/5/8/4/4/58449511/imu_bag.zip
The IMU is Polulu UM7

---

Originally posted by [atmosphericvibes](https://answers.ros.org/users/30709/atmosphericvibes/) with karma: 26 on 2017-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1